# Having an issue with dynamic component loading in IE11

Tags: angular

I'm loading a component and passing an object after loading ..

```
  @Component({
selector:"formatter-component-cell",
directives:[NgSwitch,NgSwitchDefault],
template:`
  <div #component ></div>`})    
export class FormatterComponentCell {
@ViewChild('component', {read: ViewContainerRef}) component;

@Input() dataMapping:DataToConfigMap;4

@Input() gridMethods:GridMethodes;

cmpRef:ComponentRef<any>;
constructor(private resolver:ComponentResolver) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(TextBoxFormatter) .then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
        this.cmpRef = this.component.createComponent(factory);
        if (this.cmpRef) {
            this.cmpRef.instance.rowData = this.dataMapping.rowData;
            this.cmpRef.instance.config = this.dataMapping.config;
            this.cmpRef.instance.gridMethods=this.gridMethods;
        }
    });
}
```

}

but when I access

```
get name{return rowData[key];}
```

in the Component IE throws Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: 'true'. And Shows some old data;
Its weird behaviour.

//Dynamic Component

```
@Component({
selector: 'widget1',
template: `
        <span style="width: 100%" (click)="toggleEdit($event)" *ngIf="!isOnEdit">{{name}}</span>
        <input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" [(ngModel)]="name" checked="isChecked"  *ngIf="isOnEdit">`})



   export class TextBoxFormatter extends  FormatterCellComponentBase  
{

isOnEdit:boolean = false;

get name():string {
    return this.rowData["Name"];
}

set name(val) {
    this.rowData["Name"] = val;
}

constructor(private _service:GridService) {
    super();
}

toggleEdit(e:Event) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.isOnEdit = !this.isOnEdit;
}

onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        this.isOnEdit = false;
        this.gridMethods.editRow(this.rowData);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is this code `get name{return rowData[key];}`?

Comment: in the dynamically loaded component. And that is used as <div>{{name}}</div>

Comment: Is that `4` after `dataMapping` intentional?

Comment: please ignore that, 4

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer :  any luck ?

Comment: Please provide more details (more code).

Comment: Added Dynamic Component Code (TextBoxFormatter is the component)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118801/discussion-between-mahesh-valiya-veetil-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: `get name{return rowData[key];}` is still not included in the added code.

Comment: get name():string {
    return this.rowData["Name"];
}                                                                                                                please see this line and in the template I've used that

Comment: Sorry, no idea. You only load the application or do you have to type to get the exception?

Comment: when I load the application, if the enableProdMode() is called it's not showing the exception.  The surprising part is no other browser have that issue.

Comment: That `enableProdMode()` fixes the exception is expected because this exception can only occur in devMode. But you don't need to do anything but load the application to get the exception (no click, no keyboard input, ...)

Comment: yea While loading the app, its throwing the error

Comment: this is used as a formatter for a gridcell(My Own Grid). In IE its causing grid to load old data  (for eg : the deleted row is showing up  , I suspect some template cache or data cache issue)

Comment: IE does cache HTTP requests. You need to work around by adding random value query parameters or similar (I don't use IE)